# How to switch to the latest active desktop, is there a hotkey?

Tags: keyboard, desktop, mission-control

I've a little of a search but haven't found anything.

Is there a way to switch to the latest active desktop? Or should I create a special hotkey for that?

Comment: that would be the previous used ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes...........